# snapshot testing with react-test-renderer

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, jestjs, react-test-renderer

I'm trying to create a test case for App component which has the following providers.

- Store Provider
- Translation provider
- redux-persist
- Router

I'm trying to render the app which certain state, to ensure the same app is rendered. The test case passes, but I get the following as snapshot.

```
// Jest Snapshot v1, [link to jest docs]

exports[`This should Render App 1`] = `null`;

exports[`This should Render App 2`] = `null`;
```

My test case is like this,

```
const component = renderer.create(
         <App store={store} persistor={persistor} />,
  );
  let tree = component.toJSON();
  expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
```

`tree` is not null and has the rendered component. But I do not see this being written in snapshot.

npm package versions

```
"jest": "^22.4.4",
"react-test-renderer": "^16.4.0",
```

[Jest doc](https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/snapshot-testing.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue by using `.toTree()` method available in `react-test-renderer` instead of `toJSON()`.

`toMatchSnapshot()` of jest seems to accept only `ReactTestRendererTree` as apposed to `ReactTestRendererJSON`.